# Simple Harmonic Motion velocity formulas and speed

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

With s.h.m. there are two main velocity formulas (at my level):

1. $v= v_{max} cos w t  $
2. $v = w \sqrt{(x^2_{max} - x^2)}$ which simplifies to $v_{max} = wx_{max}$

In a recent question 2 worked to find the maximum speed but 1 didn't is this because 2 has x^2 which negates the positive or negative wich gives direction?

I am aware velocity and speed are different but in the case of s. h. m. I thought that the magnitude of the velocity was equal to speed.

So why doesn't formula 1 rearranged work to find maximum speed?

Answer (score 1):

Equation 1 gives you the velocity with direction, i.e. $v$ can be positive and negative depending  on the direction of motion.

In equation 2, $v$ is always positive, i.e. it gives you the absolute value of the velocity without any information on the direction.

Also, in equation 1 you have the velocity expressed as a function of time, while in equation 2 you have the velocity as a function of displacement.

From the first equation you can for instance find that the velocity is maximum when the cosine is $\pm 1$, i.e. if $\omega t = n\pi$. If you want to get a relation between $v_\mathrm{max}$ and $x_\mathrm{max}$ from the first equation, you could note that velocity and position are related by differentiation:
$$v=\frac{dx}{dt}$$

Using that $v=v_\mathrm{max}\cos\omega t$ you can integrate this equation and get:

$$x=x_0+\frac{v_\mathrm{max}}{\omega}\sin\omega t$$

where without loss of generality you can put $x_0=0$ (since it does not matter where you place your oscillator). So you end up with the equation:

$$x=\frac{v_\mathrm{max}}{\omega}\sin\omega t$$

from which you can see that $x_\mathrm{max}=v_\mathrm{max}/\omega$ which is the same relationship you found from equation 2.